# Spring @Autowired bean not found, No qualifying bean of type [...] found

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I get the following exception when trying to start my application context in a TestNG-Test:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'albumService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.yoon.archive.dao.AlbumDao net.yoon.archive.service.AlbumService.albumDa
o; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.yoon.archive.dao.AlbumDao] found for dependency: exp
ected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at [... Framework code ...]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.yoon.archive.dao.AlbumDao net.yoon.archive.service.AlbumService.albumDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.yoon.archive.dao.AlbumDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at [...]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [net.yoon.archive.dao.AlbumDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at [...]
```

As far as my understanding of building a spring application context goes I should be doing it correctly, similar questions of this nature have sadly also not given me any answers that solved the error.

Sorry for the wall of code below, but I felt it could all be relevant.

The bean that can't be autowired:

```
package net.yoon.archive.dao;

import net.yoon.archive.domain.music.Album;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class AlbumDao extends AbstractHibernateDao<Album> {

}
```

The bean I'm trying to autowire it in:

```
package net.yoon.archive.service;

import net.yoon.archive.dao.AbstractHibernateDao;
import net.yoon.archive.dao.AlbumDao;
import net.yoon.archive.domain.music.Album;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class AlbumService extends AbstractDaoService<Album> {

    @Autowired
    private AlbumDao albumDao;

    @Override
    protected AbstractHibernateDao<Album> getDao() {
        return albumDao;
    }
}
```

The test class that's creating the application context:

```
package net.yoon.archive.service;

import net.yoon.archive.TestGroups;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test(groups = { TestGroups.SERVICE_TEST })
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:applicationContext.xml" })
public class NameServiceTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private NameService nameService;

    public void testSetup() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(nameService);
    }
}
```

My applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.yoon.archive" />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
        [...]
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        [...]
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modify your transactional configuration to

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

so that Spring uses CGLIB proxies which can extend your bean classes, ie. `AlbumDao`. Alternatively, program to interfaces.

Comment: That did the trick! I overlooked that option earlier but didn't connect the dots. Thanks a lot.

Comment: _"Alternatively, program to interfaces"_ <- This was exactly my issue. By mistake I was autowiring the implementation, instead of the interface.